# Is there a way to reset an island in Campaign mode?

Tags: tropico-5

In Tropico V's campaign mode, you cycle between islands, doing missions on them. If you do a mission on an island you have been to before, the island is pretty much in the same state it was in when you left it.

So, when I did a mission which involved building an invasion force, I stuffed up and it took me a very long time to complete. Which meant I had kind of destroyed my mineral reserves etc before realising what I was doing wrong, changing my constitution and then quickly finishing the mission before the economy collapsed.

Now, I have a mission to export vast quantities of oil, set on that island. But I left the island in such a shambles that my economy pretty much immediatly falls over, and the newly founded oil industry doesn't even get going.

Does anyone know if the campaign system has a work around for this? Or have I pretty much screwed myself several missions ago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have completed the game two times now actually, and Im afraid that there is **no** restarting option, besides loading a previous game.

I had the same problemes as you face. And since I lacked the intelligence to save my progress after each mission, I had to start over from some old savegame!

But, my advice to you, is to save after each finished mission, so you can go back and load from a point where you might be able to do things the right way.